# use-package :defer t and add-hook

Tags: use-package, autoload

If I have something like:

```
(use-package X
  :defer t
  (add-hook 'some-mode 'package-x-function))
```

Will that work as expected given that I set `:defer t` and the package *doesn't* have any "built-in" autoloads and I'm not using any of the autoload-creating use-package functions? In other words, does registering a hook *alone* take care of loading package X given that I set `:defer t`?

If not, what is the minimal additional configuration I require to make the hook work? Would I have to do something like `:commands package-x-function`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should do what you want:

```el
(use-package X
  :commands package-x-function
  :init
  (add-hook 'some-mode 'package-x-function))
```

The `:commands` directive will generate an autoload for `package-x-function`, and the `:init` directive will immediately add it to the hook.  Because `:commands` implies `:defer`, the package won't be loaded immediately.  When the hook is run, the autoload will be looked up and the package will be loaded.

If you left off the `:commands` part, then you'd get a `void-function` error when the hook is run, because Emacs won't have a definition for `package-x-function` and there's no autoload to tell it how to get one.

Comment: Normally if the package wasn't deferred, you'd put the `add-hook` in the `:config` section, so that it wouldn't occur until the package was loaded. In this case thanks to the autoload created by `:commands`, it makes sense to put it in the `:init` right, otherwise there would never be a "trigger" run to autoload the package.

Comment: Forgot to phrase my comment as a question. Would appreciate a confirmation on that.

Comment: Correct.  You need something to load the package, and so using the hook to do so means that it needs to be in `:init` rather than `:config`.